# Defining nth-of-type

Tags: html, css

I have 3 identical divs, and I want to change the first span in the 2:nd one with css, but no matter, what I will type: `nth-of-type(2)` with class, or `first-of-type` with span, the first two spans are changing. I need just the first one.

This is my code

```css
.info:nth-of-type(2) span:first-of-type {
  color: #f4fffe;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.price` is the first `div` inside its parent, so `:nth-of-type(2)` doesn't match. I don't see the "3 exactly the same divs".

Comment: thanks for your comments and help - I've just find the answer with using ">" :)

Comment: It is not SO policy to edit a question and invalidate given answers, which mine now became. Since mine is the only one left I will update it accordingly, but next time, ask a new question or make a comment at a given answer to get a second sample/variant.

Comment: I need to ask, you just wrote in a comment using `>` solved your issue (also wrote that under my answer), how come you changed to an answer that doesn't use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the nth-of-type on your .info instead of your .price

```css
.info:nth-of-type(2) .price span:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this, using the direct child selector `>`

Note that the direct child selector `>` is needed if you ever add a second element, which I did as a sample, or else that element'f first span will be selected as well

*Sample code update based on an edit of the original question*

```css
.month24 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.info:nth-of-type(2) .price > span:first-child {
  color: #f40;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
    <div class="month24">
      <span>85<sup>99</sup></span>
      <span>dollars</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if it's the first span in `info`, you do like this

```css
.month24 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.info:nth-of-type(2) > span:first-child {
  color: #f40;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
    <div class="month24">
      <span>85<sup>99</sup></span>
      <span>dollars</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked for me, too! @ChickenLeg - Then please accept the answer :)

Comment: Your solution works, but so does the OP's original code except that he/she was looking for `.price ` , rather than `.info`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well the OP just changed his original question to `.info` and invalidated the given answers ... which is not according to SO policies

Comment: SO policies notwithstanding, the original question was "I have 3 exactly the same divs, and I want to change the first span in the middle one with css," - This clearly indicates that it is the middle div that is being looked for.

Comment: @ScottMarcus And the code was `.price:nth-of-type(2) span:first-of-type {` then changed to `.info:nth-of-type(2) span:first-of-type {`, which invalidates any given answer using the first, or you disagree? ... And that middle were assumed to be many `.price`, but after the update one would of course assume `.info`, or you disagree with that too?

Comment: @LGSon I interpreted the question and problem correctly before the question was edited as I think others did as well. To me it was clear that the outer-most div was the one that would be repeated 3 times. That made it clear that the problem was with the `.price` selector.

Comment: @ChickenLeg I have now updated my answer. Also check the note I added so you'll see how any future change with additional elements might cause issues.

Answer (score -1):

Your original code works just fine. The `>` selector can be used, but `:first-of-type` works as well. You need to run it with three `.info` `div` elements and use a color that is easy to spot.

```css
.info:nth-of-type(2) span:first-of-type {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="info">
  <span>Plan</span>
  <div class="price">
    <span>95<sup>99</sup></span>
    <span>dollars</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting that there is a down vote when the answer is correct.

Comment: Since your answer coloring 2 spans, and neither mine nor the accepted one does that, it might not be that strange if someone downvoted, if someone believes it should only be 1.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, **there is no way** (at least none I know of) to select nth-of-type of a class:

```
.price:nth-of-type(2) span:first-of-type {
color: #f4fffe; }
```

You need to do this **manually**.